# Oil + UV radiation = cholecalciferol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-biology

According to a web site about health (Antranik):

> The oil that naturally comes from our skin is a type of cholesterol. 
>   Whenever we stand under direct sunlight, the ultraviolet rays react
>   with this oil.  The ultraviolet radiation breaks some chemical bonds
>   in the oil so that it forms a different molecule.  This molecule is
>   known as the infamous Vitamin D3 which is why it’s also called the
>   “sunshine vitamin.”

According to the web site, cats lick this converted oil off their fur to get Vitamin D (cholecalciferol).

What exactly is the reaction here? How could UV radiation be converting oil into a hormone? I thought hormones were much more complex molecules than oils, not simpler molecules.

Comment: The wikipedia page on Cholecalciferol gives a more scientific and accurate  account of this process.

Comment: @porphyrin The article does not completely describe the reaction, but only outlines it in general terms. Also, the article says it happens within the skin, but for a cat, according to the article quoted, it does not happen on the skin but on the fur of the cat.

Comment: Estherols such as cholesterol aren't simple oils. They are immersed in an oil matrix, yes, but the molecules are completely different; check out the structures of triglycerids vs. cholesterol in Google Images or similar. However the difference between cholesterol and cholecalciferol is smaller; cholesterol is transformed to 7-dehydrocholesterol in the body, and then the sun breaks this intermediate in a single step to produce vitamin D3. Note that this isn't the only way to get vitamin D; you can also eat vitamin D2, manufactured industrially from vegetables.